# How to call Apps Script from iOS and Android Apps?

Tags: android, ios, google-apps-script

I created Apps Script and published it to be accessible via API.

Now I want to call it from iOS and Android Apps.

But I see the following message on https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/mobile

> Note: It is highly recommended to call G Suite APIs from a server environment rather than a mobile environment.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: if you want to run your APIs on both ios and android, you need your code in a server enviornment. not sure what you are asking here.....

Comment: Client code in mobile - server environment - and that means? My question is very clear. G provides client SDK but does not recommends it?

Comment: mobile environment = on the client. server environment .... on the server. Look into Cloud functions for firebase (for example). You can write code on the client (on the mobile app itself) or write code in the server to handle your requests. THAT is what is highly recommended. Hopefully that clears it up.